# Is there a way to create the following dataframe in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, join

I am new to python and I need to do the following. Not sure if it is called 'join'.
I have 2 data frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'column_A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
'column_B': ['B0', 'B0', 'B1', 'B1']}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'column_C': ['1', '2', '3'],
'column_D': ['0', '3.5', '7.5'],
'column_E': ['3.6', '7.6', '11'])
```

and I need to create the following dataframe:
df_final:

```
column_A column_B column_C column_D column_E
A0  B0  3   7.6 11.0
A1  B0  3   7.6 11.0
A2  B1  3   7.6 11.0
A3  B1  3   7.6 11.0
A0  B0  2   3.6 7.5
A1  B0  2   3.6 7.5
A2  B1  2   3.6 7.5
A3  B1  2   3.6 7.5
A0  B0  1   0   3.5
A1  B0  1   0   3.5
A2  B1  1   0   3.5
A3  B1  1   0   3.5
```

when I use concat does not give me exactly the above out come.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want the cartesian product of both dataframes. One way is using `merge` creating a helper column where to merge on:

```
df1.assign(key=0).merge(df2.assign(key=0), on='key').drop(['key'], axis=1)

     column_A column_B column_C column_D column_E
0        A0       B0        1        0      3.6
1        A0       B0        2      3.5      7.6
2        A0       B0        3      7.5       11
3        A1       B0        1        0      3.6
4        A1       B0        2      3.5      7.6
5        A1       B0        3      7.5       11
6        A2       B1        1        0      3.6
7        A2       B1        2      3.5      7.6
8        A2       B1        3      7.5       11
9        A3       B1        1        0      3.6
10       A3       B1        2      3.5      7.6
11       A3       B1        3      7.5       11
```